# Hello I am upgrading my aunt's laptop Dell Inspiron b130 installed ubuntu 14.04.3.and its really slow

Tags: 14.04, dell, inspiron

What is the highest Ubuntu i can install without it being so slow? Thanks

Here are the specs:

```
Specifications
Name    Dell Inspiron B130
Processor   Intel Pentium-M 730 1.73GHz
Screen  14.1“ WXGA
RAM 512MB
HDD 60GB
Optical Drive   DVD-ROM/CD-RW
Graphics    Intel Graphics Media Accelerator 900
Network 10/100 Ethernet, Dell 1370 802.11g Wireless or Dell 1470 802.11a/b/g Wireless
Other   3 x USB2.0
Linux Compatibility
Device  Compatibility   Comments
Processor   Yes 
Screen  Yes 
HDD Yes 
Optical Drive   Yes 
Graphics    Yes 
Sound   Yes Use the snd-hda-intel module
Ethernet    Yes 
Wireless    Partial 
56K Modem   Not Tested  
USB Yes
```

Answer (score 1):

Judging by those specs, normal Ubuntu is not the way to go. Ubuntu may be good on old computers, but 512MB RAM seems like it's just too little for Unity. If you really want Ubuntu, I recommend installing [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/). It's not the prettiest, but it's lightweight and meant to run on older computers, such as that one.
If you really like the Unity interface, 12.04 is really your only other option. It may be better and it may not. You'll have to test this one out yourself.

Comment: Zacharee1 is correct . . . 512MB is too little memory for Ubuntu. Lubuntu can work, but I've never found even Lubuntu to work well with less than 1GB. People these days expect a snappy response, they leave 20 browser tabs open, they leave multiple applications running. That takes processor speed and memory.

Answer (score 0):

RAM is very low on this little machine. It should at least have 1GB, better 2 GB (2x1GB). Then it's fun – promised!

One of my boxes is similar, it's a Dell D600 in a docking-station, also with Pentium M. Since Ubuntu has switched to PAE Linux-Kernel you may need the 'forcepae' boot-option. Did you test anything yet?

Generally it's recommended to use a Desktop-Environment that gets along w/o 3-D Accelaration. This is not Ubunutu itself then. I recommend Kubuntu 14.04.1 since itself & it's Kernel 3.13 has support 'til 2019 - 3D-Acceleration for the DE can be switched off permanentely in the settings or temporarely using ALT+SHIFT+F12. It still uses KDE4 -which has matured. I would also NOT recommend upgrading to 16.04 LTS with that kind of graphics. It is well supported from free Radeon-driver. Don't remember how this was with WIFI - but thats feasable. Needs some more info probably.

Lubuntu/Xubuntu would also have been candidates - if they just were LTS - but they were not then. Kubuntu still supports KDE4 via the backports-ppa.

Downloadlink: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/14.04.1/release/

backports-ppa: https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/backports

Info on ppa: http://scarlettgatelyclark.com/2015/kubuntu-kde-4-14-3-bugfix-release-for-trusty-is-now-available/

Why to choose 14.04.1 - Wiki - LTS-Kernel-release-schedule:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack#Kernel.2BAC8-Support.Ubuntu_Kernel_Release_Schedule

If there are any other questions feel free to ask here - as there will still be opportunities for optimizations, like using Synaptic as package-manager instead of Muon. Completely purge KMail and replace it with Thunderbird. Use OpenGLES.

Also it's recommended to check the hard-disks life-cycle-condition. Be prepared to have to replace it in order not to suffer data-loss.

Hence its always arguable why to invest into old hardware, it may extent the timespan to planned save some money to get a nice replacement. Which in my case was a AM1 µboard, costing less than 200 bucks for a workstation with all parts.

Comment: Some questions that come to my mind having been the "luck-smith" for people desiring to a Linux-System to replace their Windows...

Who will administer the system? You or Aunt ? Can you teach her, or will will you set the system to automatic security-updates?

Check on what she desperately needs/misses beforehand. If shes beeing using Firefox/Thunderbird before, incorporate these data into the new install. Having all the old-bookmarks/emails back, makes a big-smile on peoples faces ;-) For the own sake, it's also pretty interesting to write down some notes in preparation and reflection...

Comment: Thanks for the advice...I ordered 2 gigs of ram for it to see if it will be speedy enough. Thank you again

Comment: Would be interesting to get to know some details on progress :-)